# Citations and footnotes together in references

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm writing a paper for a historical journal, and unlike in astronomy (my main field) they want their citations and footnotes combined into one numbered list.

See:
https://royalsocietypublishing.org/rsnr/for-authors#question2

Now they don't have a tex template, but the physics journal

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/proceedings-of-the-royal-society-a-latex-template/rfbwzkqsqdmv

So I was wondering if there was an easy way to make the reference style compliant to the notes and records journal. Maybe do everything through footnotes/endnotes somehow?

Comment: The way I read their Guidelines, they request to have every part of an article in a seperate part / page. Looks like the way I needed to write the manuscript for Plant Physiology. Do you have a link to a file of Notes and Records that can be used as reference / example?

Comment: @alchemist here is an example of an open access one https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsnr.2022.0042

Comment: Thanks @Coolcrab … that’s a really interesting article too. I get the idea how they want to have the manuscript submitted. Let me think about that and I come back to you.